# How to get a Pure Black Ubuntu Theme

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I need a pure black theme for Ubuntu Gnome. The themes that I am finding are greyish-black. Please recommend some pure black theme that I can use with Ubuntu.

Comment: [This](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013664/) theme looks great. Try it.

Comment: Flat-remix is an incredible theme with a very dark variant (the Darkest-Solid-NoBorder options). [application themes](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gtk). [shell themes](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome)

Comment: @wizardpurple Thanks for the recommendation. I am loving it. Just made some changes to the css file of the shell theme as solid was not available by default for the shell theme.
I have a problem, whenever I use other theme than Yaru dark, ubuntu software gets light theme. I don't use the store always, still, it would be better to get it matched with my theme.

Comment: @Amartya Sinha glad you like it, it's a great theme. The snap store can only use themes that are the the [gtk-common-themes](https://snapcraft.io/install/gtk-common-themes/ubuntu#install) snap by default.

Comment: @Amartya Sinha the flat-remix-gtk theme is in the [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/flat-remix-gtk) now. So if you also install the snap, and follow the instructions on the store page, it should fix theming for snaps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Yaru Dark theme in gnome?

Install Gnome Tweaks

Select ‘Appearance’ in the sidebar
Locate the Shell section
Select ‘Yaru Dark’ from the menu adjacent

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But, it is greyish black. I need some pure black theme (#000000 or some nearest color).